# Converting geometry_dump to Point geometry vertex

Tags: postgis, well-known-binary

If this was a Point geometry `010100000001DE02098A1B52C090A0F831E62E4640`, is it possible to
represent the above [geometry_dump](http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-svn/geometry_dump.html) Point Vertex. I am trying with `St_collection`...,